# Dots in Fibonacci spiral

Tags: geometry

How can we prove that the dots in the center of the squares in Fibonacci spiral (see the image) can be connected by 2 perpendicular (to each other) lines?

[image]

Comment: Compute the coordinates of the $n-$th dot.

Comment: Don’t know how to do it

Comment: This looks like a really cool problem. But the question post is really not up to par. Please consider reading our [guidelines on asking questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and editing your question to better fit them.

Comment: **Why such a question should be closed ?** The asker doesn't know which track can be taken. He/she has produced a nice drawing (this is sufficiently rare to be underlined). Moreover, such a question is really interesting.

Comment: See here for the coordinates: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916048/a-little-help-for-building-the-fibonacci-spiral-in-a-particular-reference-system

Comment: @JeanMarie The quality of the _problem_ ought to be irrelevant. And there are ways to avoid [no clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) even though one thinks one has no idea. Even if it's just loose ideas about approaches which might work. For instance, he probably knows something about what it means for points to lie on a line, or for two lines to be perpendicular. Even without knowing exactly how to apply that to this problem, that's the kind of things we would like question posts to contain.

Comment: I would like to post a solution for this interesting question, but I fear that as you have not shown any attempt of your own, it is likely to be deleted anytime soon.

Comment: I hope not, I thought of it as a fractal (scaling doesn’t change the pic), but it was wrong